# how to programmatically show and hide action bar on one activity

Tags: android

i got this one activity wherein i need to hide actionbar on the login interface then once login it will show the action bar.i got one activity only. if i put getActionBar on the main activity it gives me error.

heres the code:

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


ViewPager viewPager;
PagerAdapter adapter;
ProgressDialog pDialog;
ImageView imgLogo;
Menu menu1;

ImageView header;
ImageView footer;


int[] bookCover = new int[] { 

                    R.drawable.image1, 
                    R.drawable.image2,
                    R.drawable.image3,

                    };


@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setupFacebookConnect(savedInstanceState);

    imgLogo = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.logo);
    share = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.share);

    // Locate the ViewPager in viewpager_main.xml
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    // Pass results to ViewPagerAdapter Class
    adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(this, bookCover);
    // Binds the Adapter to the ViewPager
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    final OnPageChangeListener pageChangeListener = new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {

        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {

            final int pos = position;
            share.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    switch(pos) {
                    case 0:

                        break;
                    case 1: 

                        break;
                    case 2:

                        break;                                              
                    case 3:

                        break;                                              

                    }

                }
            });
         // When changing pages, reset the action bar actions since they are dependent
         // on which page is currently active. An alternative approach is to have each
         // fragment expose actions itself (rather than the activity exposing actions),
         // but for simplicity, the activity provides the actions in this sample.           
        invalidateOptionsMenu();

        }

    };      
    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(pageChangeListener);
    pageChangeListener.onPageSelected(0);


    facebook_connect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.facebook_login);
    facebook_connect.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            if (isFacebookConnected()) {
                disConnectFacebook();
            } else {
                connectFacebook();
            }

        }
    });


    // Shared Preferences
    mSharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0);

}

 @SuppressLint({ "InlinedApi", "NewApi" })
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        this.menu1 = menu;

        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

        menu.findItem(R.id.action_previous).setEnabled(viewPager.getCurrentItem() > 0);

        // Add either a "next" or "finish" button to the action bar, depending on which page
        // is currently selected.
        MenuItem item = menu.add(Menu.NONE, R.id.action_next, Menu.NONE,(viewPager.getCurrentItem() == adapter.getCount() - 1)
                        ? R.string.action_finish
                        : R.string.action_next);

        item.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);

        return true;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int itemId = item.getItemId();
        if (itemId == R.id.action_previous) {
            // Go to the previous step in the wizard. If there is no previous step,
            // setCurrentItem will do nothing.
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(viewPager.getCurrentItem() - 1);
            return true;
        } else if (itemId == R.id.action_next) {
            // Advance to the next step0.0 in the wizard. If there is no next step, setCurrentItem
            // will do nothing.
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(viewPager.getCurrentItem() + 1);
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


private Session.StatusCallback statusCallback = new FBSessionStatus();

public void setupFacebookConnect(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Settings.addLoggingBehavior(LoggingBehavior.INCLUDE_ACCESS_TOKENS);

    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (session == null) {
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            session = Session.restoreSession(this, null, statusCallback,
                    savedInstanceState);
        }
        if (session == null) {
            session = new Session(this);
        }
        Session.setActiveSession(session);
        if (session.getState().equals(SessionState.CREATED_TOKEN_LOADED)) {
            session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(this)
                    .setCallback(statusCallback));
        }
    }
}

public boolean isFacebookConnected() {
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    return (session.isOpened()) ? true  : false;

}

public void connectFacebook() {
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (!session.isOpened() && !session.isClosed()) {
        getActionBar().show();
        session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(this)
                .setCallback(statusCallback));       
    } else {
    Session.openActiveSession(this, true, statusCallback);

    }
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Session.getActiveSession().addCallback(statusCallback);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    Session.getActiveSession().removeCallback(statusCallback);
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    Session.saveSession(session, outState);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode,
            resultCode, data);
}

public class FBSessionStatus implements Session.StatusCallback {
     @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
            onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
        }
}

public void disConnectFacebook() {
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (!session.isClosed()) {
        session.closeAndClearTokenInformation();
        viewPager.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        MenuItem item1 = menu1.findItem(R.id.action_next);
        item1.setVisible(false);
        MenuItem item2 = menu1.findItem(R.id.action_previous);
        item2.setVisible(false);



        imgLogo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        //btnLoginTwitter.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        share.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    }

}

private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        // Check if the user is authenticated and
        // a deep link needs to be handled.
        if (state.isOpened()) {

            MenuItem item1 = menu1.findItem(R.id.action_next);
            item1.setVisible(true);
            MenuItem item2 = menu1.findItem(R.id.action_previous);
            item2.setVisible(true);
            //getActionBar().show();

            share.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            //btnLoginTwitter.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            //btnShare.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);     

            viewPager.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            imgLogo.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);



        } 
    }

public void shareImage(String name, String caption, String desc, String link, String picture ) {

    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("name", name);
    params.putString("caption", caption);
    params.putString("description", desc);
    params.putString("link", link);
    //params.putString("picture", "https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10203610233686079&set=a.10203610230766006.1073741829.1523023247&type=1&theater");
    params.putString("picture", picture);

    WebDialog feedDialog = (
        new WebDialog.FeedDialogBuilder(MainActivity.this,
            Session.getActiveSession(),
            params))
        .setOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {

            @Override
            public void onComplete(Bundle values,
                FacebookException error) {
                if (error == null) {
                    // When the story is posted, echo the success
                    // and the post Id.
                    final String postId = values.getString("post_id");
                    if (postId != null) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                            "Successfuly posted!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        // User clicked the Cancel button
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, 
                            "Publish cancelled", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                } else if (error instanceof FacebookOperationCanceledException) {
                    // User clicked the "x" button
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, 
                        "Publish cancelled", 
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    // Generic, ex: network error
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                        "Error posting story", 
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }



        })
        .build();
        feedDialog.show();

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private boolean isSubsetOf(Collection<String> subset, Collection<String> superset) {
        for (String string : subset) {
            if (!superset.contains(string)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
     }





}
```

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html tells you and warns you... bad design concept.

Comment: i read that, but cant find any solution , thanks anyway

Comment: You will want to read more closely b/c there's a whole section on it.  Here's a direct link so you can't miss it: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Removing

Answer (score 94):

For class extending **Activity** :

```
getActionBar().hide();
getActionBar().show();
```

For class extending **AppCompatActivity** :

```
getSupportActionBar().hide();
getSupportActionBar().show();
```

Comment: I think, using in a try catch, may solve various situations.

Answer (score 24):

Very simple.

```
getActionbar().hide();
getActionbar().show();
```

Comment: the problem when i use that, it gives me javanullpointer. and its hard to implement it with viewpager

Comment: By the way, for naming convention purposes, it's getActionBar().hide();

You have to uppercase "Bar". :^)

Answer (score 8):

You can `hide/Show` the status bar on Android 4.1 (API level 16) and higher by using **`hide()/show()`** functionality

```
     // Hide the status bar.
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.hide();

   // Show the status bar.
    actionBar.show();
```

For more details you can visit here https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/status.html

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html

Answer (score 4):

Change your Theme from the manifest file for the desire Activity...

```
 Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar 
    or 
 Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar
```

Programmatically you can Invisible your Toolbar by this line of codes

if you extend your activity by Activity class then use below line of code to show or hide the Toolbar

```
getActionBar().hide();
getActionBar().show();
```

and if you extend your activty from AppCompact Activity then use

For class extending Activity :

getActionBar().hide();
getActionBar().show();
For class extending AppCompatActivity :

```
getSupportActionBar().hide();
getSupportActionBar().show();
```

Answer (score 3):

The `ActionBar` usually exists along `Fragments` so from the `Activity` you can hide it

```
getActionbar().hide();
getActionbar().show();
```

and from the `Fragment` you can do it

```
getActivity().getActionbar().hide();
getActivity().getActionbar().show();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can save it use sharedpreference like below

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
Button btn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    loadActionbar();
    btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.mainButton1);    
 btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View p1)
            {
                if(getActionBar().isShowing()==true){
                    getActionBar().hide();
                    saveActionBar();       
                }
                else{
                    getActionBar().show();
                    saveActionBar();
                }
            }
        })


 public void saveActionBar(){
    SharedPreferences pref=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());     
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor=pref.edit();     
    editor.putBoolean("save",getActionBar().isShowing());   
    editor.apply();
}

public void loadActionbar(){
    SharedPreferences pref=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());     
    boolean i=pref.getBoolean("save",getActionBar().isShowing());
    if(i!=true){
        getActionBar().hide();
    }
    else
        getActionBar().show();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

For **Activity**

```
getActionBar().show();
getActionBar().hide();
```

For **AppCompatActivity**

```
getSupportActionBar().show();
getSupportActionBar().hide();
```

For **Fragments**

```
getActivity().getActionbar().show();
getActivity().getActionbar().hide();
```

Answer (score -2):

This just worked for me:

```
supportActionBar?.hide()
```

Comment: Please include an explanation to your answer. Code-only answers are rarely helpful and usually get deleted. This is especially true with old questions like this where the OP has solved or moved on from their problem.