# How to make the actionbar disappear in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I need to make the action bar disappear from the screen, I've tried everything I've been able to find online, but nothing seems to work. I've tried creating my own style, which doesn't do anything, `getActionbar().hide()`, which gives me an error and doesn't compile, and `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);`, which also doesn't do anything. I really need to get rid of that action bar. I'm using a sensorLandscape orientation, but I've already tried changing it and it doesn't change anything.

The manifest:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.tanques">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape" android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

My own style:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->

    <style name="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.tanques;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements JoystickView.JoystickListener, JoystickHorizontal.JoystickListener{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final Button ShootLeft= findViewById(R.id.ShootLeft);
        Button ShootRight= findViewById(R.id.ShootRight);
        ShootLeft.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { @Override public void onClick(View v){
            Log.d("Button","ShootLeft");
        }});
        ShootRight.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { @Override public void onClick(View v){
            Log.d("Button","ShootRight");
        }});
    }

    @Override
    public void onJoystickMoved(float Percent, int source) {
        switch(source){
            case R.id.JoystickLeft:
                Log.d("Joystick", "JoystickLeft" + " Percentage: " +Math.round(Percent));
                break;
            case R.id.JoystickRight:
                Log.d("Joystick", "JoystickRight" + " Percentage: " +Math.round(Percent));
                break;
            case R.id.JoystickTurret:
                Log.d("Joystick", "JoystickTurret" + " Percentage: " +Math.round(Percent));
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `check this answer it may help you` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22891440/how-to-programmatically-show-and-hide-action-bar-on-one-activity

Comment: quita el tema del Main Activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.tanques">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

styles.xml

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"/>

</resources>
```

Put this inside your `onCreate()` in `MainActivity.java` before `setContentView()`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //add this two lines to your code to hide the system bar
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN , WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //this hides the navigation bar at the bottom of your device
    hideNavigationBar();

    final Button ShootLeft= findViewById(R.id.ShootLeft);
    Button ShootRight= findViewById(R.id.ShootRight);
    ShootLeft.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { @Override public void onClick(View v){
        Log.d("Button","ShootLeft");
    }});
    ShootRight.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { @Override public void onClick(View v){
        Log.d("Button","ShootRight");
    }});
}
```

create `hideNavigationBar()` method and call it in the `onCreate()`

```
private void hideNavigationBar(){
    getWindow().getDecorView()
               .setSystemUiVisibility(
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN |
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY |
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN |
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION |
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
               );
}
```

Comment: I´m not entirely sure where is that code supposed to go, here's my original code:

Comment: after super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); and before setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); like in my post answer

Comment: super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

            requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
            window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN , WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN)

            setContentView(R.layout.activity_picture_viewer)


        }
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Comment: like this one ?

Comment: yeap that's all , try and tell me if works correctly

Comment: Look up there in the link for the image

Comment: oh dude sorry ,my code is in kotlin , no worry I'll translate my answer to Java now , give me a second

Comment: Hi, are you there?

Comment: yeap buddy but comments are not for talking , for more help find me on Twitter @BatizGo